# How to kill a child process which it is running parallely

Tags: multithreading, node.js, asynchronous, child-process

I have spawned many child

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
  newProcess1 = spawn('node', ['File1.js']),
  newProcess2 = spawn('node', ['File2.js']),
  newProcess3 = spawn('node', ['File3.js']);
```

which will run parallely.If newProcess1 fails then newProcess2 and newProcess3 must be stopped or killed if it has not started.

How can kill a child process?

Comment: What about this `newProcess1.kill();`

Comment: @Amol M Kulkarni newProcess1 will fail it should be killed simultaneously with newProcess2 and newProcess3

Answer (score 0):

```
newProcess1.on('close', function (code) { 
  console.log('child process ' + newProcess1.pid + ' exited with code ' + code); 
  newProcess2.kill();
  newProcess3.kill();
});
```

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: In which part of code I should mention newProcess2.kill();
newProcess3.kill(); ?

Comment: This is the way Im calling all the process newProcess.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

newProcess.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});

newProcess.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process ' + newProcess.pid + ' exited with code ' + code);
});

Comment: kill them inside process1's close callback

Comment: Is it possible to call external file in this code instead of passing the string to child. var cp = require('child_process');
var child = cp.fork('./worker');

child.on('message', function(m) {
    // Receive results from child process
    console.log('received: ' + m);
});

// Send child process some work
child.send('Please up-case this string');